# Protractor: ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable of Undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, autotest

I tried to wait for an input loading. So, I used expectedconditions.elementToBeClickable like this:

```js
  it('test expected conditions', async function () {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await browser.driver.get('https://www.baidu.com');

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('kw'))), 5000);
    element(by.css('#kw')).sendKeys('protractor')
    element(by.css('#su')).click()

    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
  });
```

But there is an error message thrown out, which is:

```js
Failed: Cannot read property of 'elementToBeClickable' of undefined.
```

I am pretty sure that I can locate the input using css type of 'kw' (I just want to try expectedconditions so that I can optimize the code.). And I have imported necessary APIs, which are:

```js
import { browser, logging, element, by } from 'protractor';
import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';
```

So, anyone can tell me why does this happen? And How can I solve it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with imports.

You should import the `ExpectedConditions` from `protractor` module like this:

```
import { ExpectedConditions as EC } from 'protractor';
```

usage:

```
await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('kw'))), 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, the modification works! May I ask what is the difference between import expectedconditions in two different methods?

Comment: Hey. There are no many differences if you import the `protractor` from protractor and then declare a variable `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;` and my method. It didn't work in your case because you imported the `protractor` from `protractor/built/ptor` but it should be just `import { protractor} from 'protractor'`